# Removing Fiddle links

Tags: discussion, edits, stack-snippets, jsfiddle

We all (hopefully) know, that questions or anwser containing code lines should use a stacksnippet to demonstrate the code. A fiddle (codepen etc.) link might change, getting deleted or the content changes and the fiddle would hold no further value to the community.

I hope we are all on the same page with this and that there is no need for discussion. While I editing questions, I stumble about a different question:

**Is it ok to delete Fiddle links while editing?**

If a Fiddle link has the exact same content as the stacksnippet it holds no extra value to the question/anwser. Should it still be preserved and why? Or would it be ok to remove the link as the code is displayed in the stacksnippet already?

Same if there is only a fiddle link and just a stacksnippet. Is it ok to replace the Fiddle link with the stacksnippet or should the stacksnippet be added and the Fiddle link preserved?

IMHO there is no extra value to links that might change if the stacksnippet shows the very same code. However I found no guidelines that clarfies if it would be ok to remove those links in such cases or not.

Comment: @RobertLongson no it does not anwser the question. I not askign about posting an own anwser with someone else fiddle. I askign If a link of someone else anwser should be preservered while editing his anwaser.

Comment: Your question contains the following text **"Is it ok to replace the Fiddle link with the stacksnippet"**, amongst other questions. It's really [too broad](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) as it asks multiple questions in one which isn't allowed. I decided it would be more helpful to address one of your points though. I imagine other links will be added later to address some/all of the rest.

Comment: Adding a snippet from a fiddle IN A QUESTION is **adding value** but Snippets aren't infallible. I would NOT remove the fiddle just in case.

Comment: Long before snippets existed fiddle links were a very common support for demos. Removing them all would be **terrible** if you weren't prepared to port them back to snippets

Comment: what a bad idea, fiddle links show the user taht the silution  works and he can add more rows or columns to see if his idea works adapting the fiddle

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, these links needs to be preserved. I'm not a lawyer but I do know that JSFiddle uses a different license for their code submission then SE does. Only the OP is allowed to copy over the code from a JSFiddle to a Stack Snippet. I guess the link could be used as evidence that the proper process has been followed and the OP owns both code submissions.

Another compelling reason to keep the links: Stack Snippets some times don't cut it and then it is easier to have a JSFiddle ready, either for editing, iterating or experimenting.

You're not the one deciding if just having a stack snippet will meet the demands of my workflow. As pointed out by [charlietfl](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl): "*Fiddles can also be single click forked. Snippets can really only be forked into same page answer and have no export capability*"

Removing the links destroys value for future visitors. Those links should **not** be edited out by third parties.

Comment: I really only mean the case where stacksnippet and fiddle content is exactly the same and a fiddle hold no extra information or content. But the evidence part is very helpfull as reason. Thank you for your opinion.

Comment: Fiddles can also be single click forked. Snippets can really only be forked into same page answer and have no export capability